# How to use 'terms' for search array paramerter Elasticseach

Tags: elasticsearch

I have tried in elasticsearch 6.x. But no result.

```
PUT suciptox
{
    "mappings": {
        "data": {"properties": {
                "time_format":{ "type": "date" },
                "fieldx": { "type": "text", "fielddata":true, "index": "not_analyzed"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Get query

```
"query": { 
    "terms": { 
        "fieldx": [ "L333","xxxx"] 
    }   
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Creating mapping? Search something?

Comment: my query:
GET suciptox/data/_search
{
 "sort": [{
  "time_format": {
   "order": "asc"
  }
 }],
 "query": {
     "terms": {
       "fieldx": [
         "L333","xxxx"
       ]
     }
   
  }
 
}

Comment: I see. So you have a field called `fieldx`, and its datatype is [array type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html). Correct? And you are trying to find documents, whose `fieldx` field matches the value `[ "L333","xxxx"] `.

Answer (score 0):

According to the mapping which you provided, there is a field data which is an object type and has another field called fieldx.

so your query should be like

```
{
    "query": {
        "terms": {
            "data.fieldx": ["L333", "xxxx"]
        }
    }
}
```